# I'm trying to debug my Java project in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

i am try to add user entries external folder to project in vscode launch.json

```
   "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch WsAgentTrainingApplication",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "com.thailife.wsAgentTraining.WsAgentTrainingApplication",
            "projectName": "wsAgentTraining",
            "vmArgs" : "-DDB_CONFIG_PATH=/c/resources/db",
            "jdkPath": "${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin",
            "sourcePaths": ["c/manit"] // External folder
        }
    ]
```

it work on eclipse Debug Configuration ->  classPath -> user entries -> advanced -> add Folder someone have issue sameme please let me know about setting that Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

source paths - These are the extra source directories of the program. The debugger looks for source code from project settings by default.

This option allows debuggers to look for extra entries in external directories.

For more details kindly visit the link.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging